# How can I detect when video Vimeo finished playing react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, vimeo

I add vimeo on a page as a link and try to use onEnded event but it doesn`t work.
My code is here

```
const iframe = useRef(null)
const myCallback = () => (console.log('Video has ended'));
     <iframe
        ref={iframe}
        src='some-link'
        onEnded={() => myCallback()}          
      />
```

Cuold you please to advice me something that can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think a native `iframe` can detect the events from an embedded Vimeo video. You can refer to the official Vimeo Player API [here](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js). There are also existing React implementations of this if you opt for the component based approach.

```
import React from "react";
import Vimeo from "@u-wave/react-vimeo";

export default function App() {
  const myCallback = () => console.log("Video has ended");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Vimeo video="347119375" autoplay onEnd={() => myCallback()} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/so-react-vimeo-embed-6xt25 
Reference: https://github.com/u-wave/react-vimeo